# When do ini files in /etc/php.d/ get loaded?

Tags: php, apache

In the load order of Apache, when in the order of PHP `.ini` files are the files that are are in `/etc/php.d/` loaded? I know for `httpd` itself, `.conf` files located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` are loaded when the Apache `include ...` directive in the `httpd.conf` file is called. Are `.ini` files located in `/etc/php.d/` loaded after the entire `/etc/php.ini` file is loaded, or is there an include in `/etc/php.ini` that loads the file at a certain point?

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing to do with Apache.  The loading of PHP ini files depends on how your PHP binary is compiled.  You can configure the option *--with-config-file-scan-dir* to point to a directory at compile time.

```
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d
```

You do **not** need to add anything to your php.ini.  All .ini files in this directory will be loaded in alphabetical order **after** the initial configuration file has been loaded.  This configure switch can also be overridden by [setting an environment variable](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67389).

**Note**: To prevent this behaviour when using PHP CLI, [you can use](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45114) the switch -n on the php binary to turn off dynamic loading of ini files.