# I have the following settings in php.ini but they aren't showing up in phpinfo

Tags: php, apache, redhat, ini, apc

I have apcu enabled - version 4.0.11
Apache version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.31

This is at the end of php.ini

```
apc.cache_by_default=On
apc.file_update_protection=2
apc.filters=
apc.max_file_size=1M
apc.num_files_hint=5024
apc.stat=1
apc.write_lock=On
```

I have also tried to put it in /etc/php.d/40-apcu.ini, but it had no effect.

I restarted apache after changing the files.

The reason I am trying to enable these variables is because we are upgrading to another server and these were the values on the old server. If they are no longer needed or supported that is fine, but I could not find any documentation saying that.

EDIT: Relevant PHP info
[image: ini]
[image: apc]

Comment: If you are running PHP-FPM you may need to restart PHP service as well.

Comment: I see nothing in PHP info with "FPM"

Comment: I ran the command `systemctl stop php-fpm` and it said the service is not loaded, so that confirms what I thought before.

Comment: note "APC Support: Emulated". That means you do NOT have APC included with php. Instead you're probably running ZendOpcache.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: After updates, and further review. Zend OpCache

PHP > 5.5 doesn't included APC, hense the "APC Support Emulated" in your phpinfo. Instead, it has Zend OpCache replaces APC Opcache. APC had two parts. There does remain an APCu component of APC, for storing data, but all the settings you describe are specific to APC Opcache.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php

## You've got some troubleshooting to do

1. As you have a `php.d/40-apcu.ini`, it is possible that one of those is over-riding the values in php.ini

   - Usually the main ini file is loaded first, followed by those included in that directory, but this behavior is configurable. See: [When do ini files in /etc/php.d/ get loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958926/when-do-ini-files-in-etc-php-d-get-loaded).
2. There may be some additional specific directives in the OS, or in Apache, to force some of those settings. If you didn't find an over-ride in the included ini files, you'll have to start a deep dive on apache config, and how it is started.
3. Don't forget that apache config directives like `Directory` and `VirtualHost`, as well as `.htaccess`, can be allowed to change these settings.
4. Last but not least, in many configurations, php code itself can set these directives with the `ini_set()` function.

## Good Luck

Comment: The variables aren't even showing up in phpinfo. It's not even that they are being changed by another file. I've searched the system for those variables and the only place they exist is where I added them.

Comment: does the APC section _appear at all_ in phpinfo?
you should probably double-check the php-info for what ini files are actually being loaded.  It is possible that your version of php was not compiled with APC.dll included. Don't forget that you can be loading different ini files between cgi and cli.

Comment: Yes it does.  I have updated the question to include the relevant php info. I had to install apc after everything else was installed (someone else did the most of the installation and I'm finishing it). I honestly have no idea what cgo and cli is.

Comment: CGI - common gateway interface; cli - command line, if you are setting up a web-server, you should probably familiarize yourself with these terms...

Comment: @AllisonC, Ah, you're not running APC OpCache. http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php Answer updated.

Comment: Do I need to install something different? I ran the command `yum install php-apc` and that's what it installed. I looked up the options on the link you mentioned and didn't see the options I was missing.

Comment: `yum install php-apc` will still install opcache rather than the old ACP. The problem is _probably_ the prefixes in your config. `apc.***` != `opcache.***`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was caused by entering the wrong `phpinfo` url.

**Wrong url:**

```
http://localhost/?phpinfo=1
```

**Correct url** (note the **-1** parameter)

```
http://localhost/?phpinfo=-1
```